# how to install angular cli?i am getting problem

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I installing angular cli on my laptop for practicing angular when i installing i got error .it becomes freeze . I tried    many way for this but my problem not resolving.what is their solution

```
S F:\talent_angular> npm install -g @angular/cli.
```

```
[#########.........] / idealTree: timing idealTree Completed in 20478ms.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happen due to cached files. So you can clear the cached files and try to install again.This is command for clear cached files. `npm cache clean --force`
Sometimes it happen due to unstable network connection. Cheack your network connection and try to install

Comment: many times i have done but not resolved

Comment: So try to another node version. Uninstall your current node and try another node version install and try this again.

Comment: done but not happening anything

Comment: You can disable your  antivirus software and try install again.

Comment: all things i have done but not...

Comment: if you want can we come in zoom

Comment: now what you said i have done but another problem has come

Comment: npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

Comment: Is it ok now your problem?

Answer (score 0):

yaa many way i had tried but now it's done

1)-disable antivirus

2)- `npm cache clean --force`

3)- `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

4)- `npm install -g @angular/cli`

then not happing anything shut down laptop or eleminate running node js service
run againg step by step